# What movie is set at Hitler’s 80th birthday party in Berlin?

Tags: story-identification, movie, parallel-universe

A long time ago I watched a movie in which Nazi Germany didn't lose WW2, but made some peace agreement with western allies. The movie was set in Berlin on Hitler's 80th (?) birthday. Does anyone have any idea what this movie is called?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about science fiction and fantasy...

Comment: @SachinShekhar - Surely alternative history can be considered fantasy?

Comment: @SachinShekhar Agree with System Down.  Alternative history is fantasy.

Comment: I posted it here becuase I agree that this is some kind of fiction/fantasy

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That sounds a lot like "Fatherland", a book by Robert Harris that was turned into a TV movie of the same name in 1994 starring Rutger Hauer.

The book is set in the week leading up to Hitler's 75th birthday though, not his 80th. Very good book, but I haven't seen the TV movie.

Comment: Yepp, this was what I was looking for.

Comment: Brilliant book! The film is actually on Youtube at the moment.